# Eliminate duplicates (deduplication) in Streaming DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I have a Spark streaming processor.
The Dataframe dfNewExceptions has duplicates (duplicate by "ExceptionId").
Since this is a streaming dataset, the below query fails:

```
val dfNewUniqueExceptions = dfNewExceptions.sort(desc("LastUpdateTime"))
                                    .coalesce(1)
                                    .dropDuplicates("ExceptionId")
                                    
val dfNewExceptionCore = dfNewUniqueExceptions.select("ExceptionId", "LastUpdateTime")
    dfNewExceptionCore.writeStream
      .format("console")
//      .outputMode("complete")
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .option("numRows",5000)
      .start()
      .awaitTermination(1000)
```

**
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Sorting is not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets, unless it is on aggregated DataFrame/Dataset in Complete output mode;;
**

This is also documented here: [https://home.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-branch-2.0-docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html](https://home.apache.org/%7Epwendell/spark-nightly/spark-branch-2.0-docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html)

Any suggestions on how the duplicates can be removed from dfNewExceptions?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to follow the approach explained in the Structured Streaming Guide on [Streaming Deduplication](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#streaming-deduplication). There it says:

> You can deduplicate records in data streams using a unique identifier in the events. This is exactly same as de-duplication on static using a unique identifier column. The query will store the necessary amount of data from previous records such that it can filter duplicate records. Similar to aggregations, you can use de-duplication with or without watermarking.
>
> *With watermark* - If there is an upper bound on how late a duplicate record may arrive, then you can define a watermark on an event time column and deduplicate using both the guid and the event time columns. The query will use the watermark to remove old state data from past records that are not expected to get any duplicates any more. This bounds the amount of the state the query has to maintain.

An example in Scala is also given:

```scala
val dfExceptions = spark.readStream. ... // columns: ExceptionId, LastUpdateTime, ... 

dfExceptions 
  .withWatermark("LastUpdateTime", "10 seconds") 
  .dropDuplicates("ExceptionId", "LastUpdateTime")
```

Comment: Thank you. dropDuplicates works to eliminate duplicates. But I want to eliminate duplicates - by taking the latest "LastUpdateTime" to remove the old events. It looks like it is not possible to achieve it in streaming (even within the same chunk)?

Comment: Problem is, LastUpdateTime comes in random order. So without sorting within the chunk, I don't see how this can be achieved. Could you please elaborate what did you mean by concatenation.

Comment: As as example:
From the below 2 entries (which come in the same chunk), I want eliminate the older one:
0_7ED_25D59038A21F66638E570A8C53E4D8  3/2/2018 6:08:11 PM
0_7ED_25D59038A21F66638E570A8C53E4D8  3/8/2018 7:28:21 PM

I tried this :
val dfNewUniqueExceptions = dfNewExceptions.withWatermark("LastUpdateTime", "60 seconds").dropDuplicates("ExceptionId", "LastUpdateTime")

Expectation is, event with "3/2/2018 6:08:11 PM" should be removed.
But I see both rows are still present in the result.

Comment: I think now I understand. You do not want to eliminate duplicates but rather *select the maximum time* over the ExceptionId. This is **not** a de-duplication task.

Comment: I want to extract all events with Unique ExceptionIds. In case there are events with duplicate ExceptionIds, then I want to select the unique event which has the latest LastUpdateTime.

Comment: @Ganesha in those cases I would use `row_number`, partitioned on `ExceptionId`, sorted by `LastUpdateTime` desc, and filtering for `row_number = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [watermarking](https://databricks.com/de/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html) to drop duplicates in a specific timeframe.